# java selenium doesn't work

Tags: java, selenium

```
webdriver driver = new firefoxdriver(); 
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

this is my code. It opens an empty new window. I tried with other sites too. 
These are the versions of my java libraries 
selenium-java-3.4.0
selenium-java-3.4.0-sources
geckodriver-v0.17.0-win32
https://akphoto2.ask.fm/e1e/0c1a2/00e0/4945/b426/e7f11ef373b9/large/1535543.png
https://akphoto2.ask.fm/196/5985b/e498/4412/9e7e/6c3a2683802e/large/1534155.png

Comment: First of all, its `FirefoxDriver`. Uppercase is impotent. Try downgrade you firefox browser version, it might be compatibility issue.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't tell what if the "real" think you are asking about..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need **selenium-java-3.4.0-sources**. Add **client-combined-3.4.0-nodeps.jar** as well from **selenium-java-3.4.0** JAR.

Make sure that you are using the correct version of Gecko. Example, if your Firefox is 32-bit, then use 32-bit GeckoDriver. Use the latest version of Firefox as well.

The code that you have added should work fine.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Bob\\Documents\\java\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
      
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: this is my code and this is the error that it says:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
 at automationjava.AutomationJava.main(AutomationJava.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: com.google.common.base.Function
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more

Comment: Hi, Its most probably because your project is not setup correctly. Please check all the steps that you used to create the project. You can follow this link if you wish - http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3/

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Firefox version and whether the gecko-driver can support the particular firefox version as well. This is a compatibility issue by all guesses.

Answer (score 0):

First create service for driver.

```
service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("path/to/my/chromedriver.exe")).usingAnyFreePort().build();
service.start();
```